# HttpPost not getting triggered

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a website where I need to redirect the users according to their role. On button click, if the user is admin, redirect to another page; else reload the same page. On button click, the index page is loaded no matter who logs in. On debugging I found out, the `[HttpPost]` attribute is not triggered at all.

View:

```
@model namespace.ViewModels.LoginVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h1>User Login</h1>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <br />
    <div style="background-color: skyblue; width: 50%">
    <div style="padding-left: 1em">
        <div class="display-label" style="font-size: large">
            Enter User Info<br />
            <br />
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.empID)</div>
            <div class="editor-field">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.empID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.empID)
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br />
}
```

Controller:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {           
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginVM model) 
    {
        MySQL msql = new MySQL();            
        var empID= model.empID
        var role = msql.Select("Select `role` from empDB where `eID` = '" + empID + "'");
        if(role == "admin") 
        { 
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home"); 
        }
        else 
        {
            return View(); 
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: When you debug this, how is it failing?  What's the database query being executed?  What is the result stored in `role`?

Comment: No matter what `empID` I enter, my code doesn't check for it's `role`, the user gets redirected to the `index` page. My code queries the `empID`  and stores the role of the `empID` entered to the variable `role`.

Comment: `"my code doesn't check for it's role"` - So this entire method isn't being executed *at all*?  Then what *is* being executed?  Where is the *actual problem*?  You need to be specific, nobody here can debug this for you.

Comment: It is unclear what problem you are facing. Did you try to put a breakpoint in your code and see what is happening ? Check the values of your variables when the breakpoint hits.

Comment: My controller returns `View()` from the `[HttpGet]`. It doesn't get to  `[HttpPost]` , i.e my query isn't executed at all.

Comment: Have you tried swapping post and gets' location in your code? Technically every request has get parameters and with poor code it might get confused.

Answer (score 0):

Your HttpPost action method name is `Login`. But your razor view, you used Index!

Update your `Html.BeginForm` method call to have the correct action method name and controllername values. Then when you click on submit, it will post the form data to `/Login/Login`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{

}
```

Comment: I understand. I made the changes, still not working.

Comment: What is happening when you click on the submit button ? Is it not posting the form data to your http post action method ?

Comment: Yes, it redirects me to the same page. It seems `HttpPost` is not fired on submit button click.

Comment: My strong feeling is that, It is posting to the HttpPost action method , but inside that your if condition `if(role == "admin")` returns false ,thus it returns the same view. Why don't you put a breakpoint in your http post action method and verify that ?